# ExecuteTemplate (template.ParseGlob) loads Blank page

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm trying to load template `page.gohtml` from folder `cms/template`. When trying to view in Firefox browser it load Blank.

**handler.go** file

```
var Tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("../templates/*"))

func ServeIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p := &Page{
        Title:   "Go Projects CMS",
        Content: "Welcome to the Home Page!",
        Posts: []*Post{
            {
                Title:         "Hello World!",
                Content:       "Hey y'all, Thanks for coming",
                DatePublished: time.Now(),
            },
            {
                Title:         "This Has Comments",
                Content:       "Atlassian Just Bought Trello...GO!",
                DatePublished: time.Now().Add(-time.Hour),
                Comments: []*Comment{
                    {
                        Author:        "Davy Jones",
                        Content:       "This is something to say about something",
                        DatePublished: time.Now().Add(-time.Hour / 2),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    Tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page", p)
}
```

**cmd/main.go** file

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", cms.ServeIndex)

    fmt.Println("Server running at port 3000")
    go http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
    fmt.Scanln()
}
```

**templates/page.gohtml**

```
{{ define "page" }}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{ .Title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.10.0/css/tachyons.min.css"/>
</head>
<body class="w-100 sans-serif bg-white">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="baskerville pb5">
    {{ .Content }}
    {{if .Posts}}
        {{range .Posts}}
            {{template "post" .}}
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: always check for all errors to avoid this kind of situation. Please check the expression [Tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page", p)](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate)

Comment: That console error is unrelated to your problem, so I removed it from the question.

Comment: Check ExecuteTemplate for errors. The page struct is defined somewhere right? Also, you show the gohtml file as being in template/ but in parseglob you're checking in templates, not template

Comment: I will check for errors. Yes templates is plural. I will update the results again. Sorry, but I just started Golang few weeks back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue when I used error handling.

```
if err := Tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page", p); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Template error: %v", err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
```

Which printed "no such template comments" while I was using `defined "comment"` inside **comment.gohtml**

Sorry for posting this question, I recently started GoLang.